# Scala immutability with asynchronous computation (Akka)

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, immutability

Having this example

```
class Supervisor(numberOfWorkers: Int, numberOfMessages: Int, numberOfElements: Int) extends Actor {

    var pi: Double = _
    var numberOfResults: Int = _

    val workerRouter = context.actorOf(Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(numberOfWorkers)), name = "workerRouter")

    def receive = {
        case Calculate =>
            for (i <- 0 until numberOfMessages) workerRouter ! Work(i * numberOfElements, numberOfElements)
        case Result(value) =>
            pi += value
            numberOfResults += 1
            if (numberOfResults == numberOfMessages) {
                println(pi)
                context.stop(self)
            }
    }

}
```

Following questions come to mind when looking at this particular situation:

1. Is it possible to make `var pi` and `var nrOfResults` immutable? If yes then how?
2. Would it make sense to do so?

Comment: It doesn't make sense :-) but it do makes sense to mark it private.

Comment: @om-nom-nom, what would be the purpose of marking them private if this is an actor?  You can't get to the underlying actor instance; only the `ActorRef`.  I suppose it could make sense if someone wanted to extend this supervisor and you wanted to protect those fields form derived classes, but that's about the only case where that suggestion seems to make sense.

Comment: @cmbaxter I do understand that, but why you're against *extra* guarantees?

Comment: @om-nom-nom marking them private could complicate synchronous unit testing with `TestActorRef`

Comment: @om-nom-nom, I'm not against them per se.  I just don't generally mark my actor fields as private unless I need to, and I don't generally need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - Yes, it is possible by using become (and not having the fields at all):

```
class Supervisor(numberOfWorkers: Int, numberOfMessages: Int, numberOfElements: Int) extends Actor {

    val workerRouter = context.actorOf(Props[Worker].withRouter(RoundRobinRouter(numberOfWorkers)), name = "workerRouter")

    override def preStart = {
      context.become(myReceive(0.0, 0))
    }

    def receive = { case _ => }

    def myReceive(pi: Double, numberOfResults: Int): Receive = {
        case Calculate =>
            for (i <- 0 until numberOfMessages) workerRouter ! Work(i * numberOfElements, numberOfElements)
        case Result(value) =>
            val newPi = pi + value
            val newNumberOfResults = numberOfResults + 1
            if (newNumberOfResults == numberOfMessages) {
                println(newPi)
                context.stop(self)
            } else {
              context.become(myReceive(newPi, newNumberOfResults))
            }
    }

}
```

2 - I think it mostly makes sense to do that if you have lots of different receive methods and switch between them with become() - like you are doing some [fsm](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html) on your own. In your case I don't think you need it.